# Jsch showing error about undefined method although it is defined

Tags: java, jsch

I am using Jsch too make a ssh connection . While the same code with exactly the same jar imports works in my friends system, it doesn't work in mine.![image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your build path and your Jsch library version. You may not be using the copy of Jsch that you think you are. You may be using an older version which doesn't have that particular function.

Comment: I am using the three version of jsch.jar(0.0.9, 0.1.50, 0.1.42) and i checked the build path also.Every thing is fine. While the same code with exactly the same jar imports works in my friends system. How is it possible,but only difference is that he's using Java1.6 and i'm using java1.7

Comment: Wait, what? You're using three versions of the jar? At the same time?

Comment: yeah,I am using these three versionjsch.jar(0.0.9, 0.1.50, 0.1.42) at same time